# What are prerequisites for using perlbrew?

Tags: terminal, xcode, perl

I want to send a Perl app I wrote to a simple Mac "end-user". He's running Monterey, but he isn't a Developer, he doesn't have Xcode, and I'm going to have to hand-hold him through using the Terminal for this.

After looking unsuccessfully for an easy way to bundle up my app and locally install the CPAN modules (couldn;t get App:FatPacker to work), I decided I'd have to get him to bite the bullet and install Perlbrew and thence Perl and the CPAN modules.

Although it's not mentioned at perlbrew.pl, a C compiler is required and is not present on an off-the-shelf MacOS. The perl build fails, and a dialog box pops up saying Command Line Tools are needed, and offers to install them. Being on a slow cellular link, he had to decline until he can get to a wifi hotspot.

Before he runs into more showstoppers, I need a clear answer to this:

1. Is there a command to perform this CLT installation?
2. Is Xcode required?
3. Does he need to be registered as an Apple Developer?
4. Are there any other prerequisites for installing Perlbrew that I haven't thought of?

The first thing I do after installing MacOS is to install Xcode, so I don't have a system like his to experiment on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's Xcode is **not** required to obtain the requisite components for `perlbrew`.

There is no need to be a registered Apple Developer to install the Command Line Tools (CLI) required for `perlbrew`. Simply do:

```
xcode-select --install
```

To install Perl, follow [here](https://perlbrew.pl/) and do:

```
curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
perlbrew install-cpanm
perlbrew install perl-5.34.1
```